# Mocking a method with std::vector of windef RECT as argument using GMock version 1.21

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am having trouble in mocking the following method.

I have this code:

```
// contents of XRECT.h
using VRECT = std::vector<RECT>;

class XRECT {
public:
    virtual bool DisplayRect(VRECT rects) = 0;
}

class CXRECT : public XRECT {
public:
    virtual bool DisplayRect(VRECT rects) override;
}

// contents of XRECT.cpp
bool CXRECT::DisplayRect(VRECT rects) {
    // do something
    return true;
}

// contents of test.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include "XRECT.h"

class MockCXRECT : public CXRECT {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, DisplayRect, (VRECT rects), (override)); // hovering over the mock method shows the "Function definition for MOCK_METHOD" not found
};

TEST(Testing, Case1) {
    MockCXRECT mock;
    VRECT v;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, DisplayRect(v)).WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return(true));
}
```

When I replace VRECT with a simple data type `int` then everything works just fine. Is there a different way to define container based arguments?

I am getting error for compiling:
`error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2) noexcept(<expr>) const'`

++++
Edit:
I see the problem is not with vector but with windef.h's RECT.

Comment: You haven't said what goes wrong when using a vector. After fixing some minor compilation issues (missing `#include <vector>` and `;` at the end of class definitions), the code compiles just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/5vE6TvMYs

Comment: [tag:gmock] is for Groovy language. Read it carefully. Try to find a better tag for Google mock.

Comment: @Kevin can you recheck. I am getting error in compiling. error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2) noexcept(<expr>) const'

Comment: @Kevin Stackoverflow crashed when I tried editing my first version, and was offline for hours.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem, by adding a template overloading.

```
// contents of XRECT.h
using VRECT = std::vector<RECT>;

class XRECT {
public:
    virtual bool DisplayRect(VRECT rects) = 0;
}

class CXRECT : public XRECT {
public:
    virtual bool DisplayRect(VRECT rects) override;
}

// contents of XRECT.cpp
bool CXRECT::DisplayRect(VRECT rects) {
    // do something
    return true;
}

// contents of test.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

#include "XRECT.h"

class MockCXRECT : public CXRECT {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, DisplayRect, (VRECT rects), (override)); // hovering over the mock method shows the "Function definition for MOCK_METHOD" not found
};

TEST(Testing, Case1) {
    MockCXRECT mock;
    VRECT v;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, DisplayRect(v)).WillRepeatedly(::testing::Return(true));
}
```

Hope it helps someone who stumbles with same type of errors.
Credit goes to:
[Google Test can't find user provided equality operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049803/google-test-cant-find-user-provided-equality-operator)